# Certain elements by data-tag - regex maybe?

Tags: jquery, regex, selector

Right now i get an element based on a data tag, it must be depending on the elements **article** OR **aside** and not all the other elements.

```
    placeholder = $('article[data-tag="blah"]').length
      ? $('article[data-tag="blah"]')
      : $('aside[data-tag="blah"]');
```

It can be done easier I guess....
I have already tried this:

```
    placeholder = $('article[data-tag="blah"]') || $('aside[data-tag="blah"]');
```

No success ofcourse because jQuery will never return undefined.
Is there a way to do it with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab all the articles and asides, then filter by the attribute:

```
 $("article, aside").filter('[data-tag="blah"]')
```

Comment: To bad there is no regex solution, but I think this is the best answer :-)

Comment: Regex is for strings.  You are trying to select DOM nodes.  It is not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
placeholder = $('article[data-tag="blah"]');
if (placeholder.length == 0) {
    placeholder = $('aside[data-tag="blah"]');
}
```

Comment: what you do is actualy the "long-hand" way of my line.

Comment: I don't understand why you accepted the other answer. It returns the wrong answer.